# Dynamically passing SQL parameters in Golang

Tags: sql-server, go

I have a `SELECT` query like below in the database table as constant.

```
select * from dbo.student where dob > @date_of_birth and grade = @grade
```

I will be getting the parameters and values from a Kafka message for  like below and I needs to replace the two parameters with this Kafka message value in Golang. This table and parameters can be different for each query in the database table. So i need to write a generic function to replace the params if any table or any number parameters to be passed.

```
{
    "message": [{
        "sql_table": "student",
        "input_params": [{
                "key": "@date_of_birth",
                "value": "2012-03-03"
            },
            {
                "key": "@grade",
                "value": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Since the column name `dob` does not match the parameter name `date_of_birth`, the `input_params` in the kafka message are simply NOT sufficient (i.e. it does not carry enough information) to create a generic func that will generate valid SQL queries.

Comment: @mkopriva disagree. We're not matching to the column. We're matching to the query parameter names in the stored SQL.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn _you_ may be matching to parameter names, but is John Scott also? Given the kafka message in the question how would _you_ generate the query in the question? And how would you generalize this to a single function that can generate queries for any `"sql_table"` with arbitrary sets of `"input_params"`?

Comment: @mkopriva He already has the query stored in the db. He wants to use the `student` key to retrieve that exact statement stored in the db, and then execute the statement with the received parameter values. So there's nothing to generate. (This would be **easy** on pretty much any platform but Go).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn fair enough, I haven't noticed that the query already exists in the db as a constant, I thought the SQL itself needed to be generated from the kafka message. But are you sure Go has an issue with named parameters? The readme you linked to in your answer is 9 years old and, while I haven't used named parameters myself, I've seen code that does use them and it didn't seem like something that would be difficult to generate.

Comment: I spent some time checking docs for better examples, but didn't find anything. I'd **LOVE** to be proved wrong about that, and take my lumps there gladly.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.20.2#Named, the docs also contain an example. For the question at hand you'd basically do something like: `db.Query("<sql string>", sql.Named("date_of_birth", v1), sql.Named("grade", v2))`.

Comment: Yay! That's enough you should put in an answer. I'll upvote it (and delete mine).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure the db driver that you're using does have support for named parameters (go-mssqldb [does](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb#executing-stored-procedures), for example), then you can do the following:

Unmarshal the kafka message into a struct, loop over the input params to create a list of args (of type `[]any`), in the loop's body use each input params object to create an [`sql.NamedArg`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.20.2#NamedArg) value, then use `...` to "unpack" the args when calling the `db.Query()` method.

```golang
type KafkaMessage struct {
    Message []Message `json:"message"`
}

type Message struct {
    SQLTable    string        `json:"sql_table"`
    InputParams []InputParams `json:"input_params"`
}

type InputParams struct {
    Key   string `json:"key"`
    Value any    `json:"value"`
}
```

```golang
func ExecQuery(db *sql.DB, m Message) (*sql.Rows, error) {
    queryString := "..." // based on m.SQLTable get the correct SQL query string

    args := make([]any, len(m.InputParams))
    for i, pp := range m.InputParams {
        name := pp.Key[1:] // drop the leading "@"
        args[i] = sql.Named(name, pp.Value)
    }

    return db.Query(queryString, args...)
}

// ...

var km KafkaMessage // unmarshal the kafka message into km
rows, err := ExecQuery(db, km.Message[0])
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    // ...
}
```